# Unmarshalling MTOM message using Camel Spring-WS and JAXB dataformat

Tags: jaxb, spring-ws, apache-camel, mtom

1) Is there a way to unmarshall MTOM message using Camel Spring-WS component?

2) I tried with Camel JAXB dataformat. It didn't work. Datahandler doesn't have any content. Does JAXB dataformat support MTOM?

```
<dataFormats>
    <jaxb id="jaxb" contextPath="com.mycompany.hr.jaxb"/>
</dataFormats>

<route>
    <from uri="spring-ws:rootqname:{http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas}HolidayRequest?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping" />
    <unmarshal ref="jaxb"/>
    <process ref="testProcessor" />
</route>
```

3) I thought MTOM is not enabled in JAXB dataformat. So I created a custom dataformat using MTOM enabled JAXB2Marshaller. But still facing the same issue.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.xml.transform.Source;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormat;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;

public class MtomDataFormat implements DataFormat {

    public void marshal(Exchange arg0, Object arg1, OutputStream arg2)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public Object unmarshal(Exchange exchange, InputStream is) throws Exception {
        Source source = exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter().mandatoryConvertTo(Source.class, is);

        Jaxb2Marshaller mar = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        mar.setContextPath("com.mycompany.hr.jaxb");
        mar.setMtomEnabled(true);
        return mar.unmarshal(source);
    }

}
```

Spring configuration

```
<bean id="endpointMapping"
    class="org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.bean.CamelEndpointMapping">
</bean>

<bean id="testProcessor" class="TestProcessor" />

<bean id="mtomDataFormat" class="MtomDataFormat" />

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="spring-ws:rootqname:{http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas}HolidayRequest?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping" />
        <unmarshal ref="mtomDataFormat"/>
        <process ref="testProcessor" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: JAXB was designed to support MTOM and does so seamlessly when used with a JAX-WS implementation.  Hopefully Spring-WS takes advantage of this functionality.

Comment: @Sujee: I don't see anything wrong with your DataFormat approach. What error are you getting, exactly? Does your *unmarshal* method run? It sounds like it returns an object (DataHandler instance?) that's not null? If so, the unmarshaller is doing its basic job--creating objects from XML. What properties are missing from the resulting object? All of them?